# How to give contractors proper access to my work process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, ssh, jenkins

I work with Rails and deploy applications to servers using Capistrano. I have a Jenkins server (on my own linode).

What I'd like to know is how to setup a contractor so they have enough access to get work done and use the tools I have (like Jenkins), but not allow them to cause any critical damage.

The workflow might be as so:

- Commit changes to private git repo
- Deploy to Jenkins
- Deploy changes to staging server (my linode)
- Deploy changes to live server (client's linode)

I use SSH for everything, but I'm wondering if I might be allowing users too much access in that they might be able to run sudo commands and change user passwords and bypass the SSH key/pair auth. Should each user have a limited Linux user account (maybe share the same limited account), and add their SSH key(s) to that?

My other question is, can I deploy to staging/live servers with Jenkins, and so only grant access to those servers from my Jenkins server?

Can I do all this by only allowing developers access to the git repo? Jenkins tracks that, then deploys to staging/live?

Comment: You shouldn't deploy into production by jenkins or any other hook, or utility. It should be initiated only by a human.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Currently, I use capistrano, so it is initiated via the applications root (which uses a deploy.rb file). This, however, requires that whatever user runs the command to have SSH access to the server they are deploying to. You think it would be wise if only I could deploy to live server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, i think the apporach should be the next.

1. Setup jenkins to run test after commit is pushed done to gitolite or whatever you use, and email about results everybody.
2. Allow contractors to deploy to staging - since they need to do testing.
3. Only you can deploy to production.

Also you shouldn't give them sudo on staging machine. Just setup a deployment role which gives access to the directory with code. Because you even'don't need do server restarts if you use passenger(just use touch %RAILS_ROOT%/tmp/restart.txt , if you know what i mean) And setup the ruby env via rvm